# secure url getting notice message

Tags: security

I am getting "i" In my url. It shows that

"www.website.com is encrypted with 128-bit encryption. However, this page includes other resources which are not secure. These resources can be viewed by others while in transit, and can be modified by an attacker to change the look of the page.

The connection uses TLS 1.2.

The connection is encrypted and authenticated using AES_128_GCM and uses ECDHE_RSA as the key exchange mechanism"

Can any one have this issue ?

How to resolve it ?

Thanks

Comment: _“However, this page includes other resources which are not secure.”_ – that _is_ the issue right there. If you want to avoid that – then _don’t_ include resources via `http://`.

Answer (score 0):

You are including files by `http` instead of `https` in the HTML of the response itself. You need to substitute this to use the correct protocol instead. You can precede your includes with `//` instead of `http://` or `https://` in order to allow the browser to get the scripts by the same protocol the site is served by.